# how to share perl array of hash reference with php

Tags: php, perl, serialization

I need to pass array of hash references to php so that php can used that data.

What I doing?

I am serializing perl array of hash references using PHP::Serialize module and storing into database. But while reading it i am facing issue.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use PHP::Serialization qw(serialize unserialize);
my @rss_feed_result = ({
                            'data'=> 'here',
                            'id'=> 1,
                            },
                        );

my $rss_feed_result = serialize(\@rss_feed_result);
//storing it to database then
```

Now I am reading the same data in php by unserialize it and getting below output after unserialize which is not proper.

```
<?php
.....read data from database into $perl_serialize_data
$perl_serialize_data = "HERE PERL SERIALIZE DATA";
print_r(unserialize($perl_serialize_data));
?>
```

Below is the output.

```
(
    [0] => {
    [1] => 'data'=>
    [2] => 'here',
    [3] => 'id'=>
    [4] => 1,
    [5] => },
)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You haven't shown how you unserialize the data in PHP.

Comment: just take the perl serialized data into string in php and use unserialize function.

Comment: Yes, you already said that. You haven't **shown** how you do it. Do not describe what your code does when asking questions; that forces people to guess what you're doing, and they might guess wrong. Instead, *show* the exact code you use.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  - i hope it is fine to you now.

Comment: Any luck to achieve this sharing?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using `use warnings` you would have gotten this warning:

```
Possible attempt to separate words with commas at foo.pl line 1.
```

With `qw()` you are trying to quote that data structure as single words. The result looks like this in Perl:

```
("{", "'data'=>", "'here',", "'id'=>", "1,", "},")
```

But you don't want a list. You want the data structure. Instead, you will probably want to do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PHP::Serialization qw(serialize unserialize);
my $rss_feed_result = {
  'data' => 'here',
  'id'   => 1,
};

my $php = serialize($rss_feed_result);
```

If you have a list of these hash refs, you can still use your array.

```
my @rss_feed_results = (
  {
    'data' => 'here',
    'id'   => 1,
  },
  {
    'data' => 'there',
    'id'   => 2,
  },
  {
    'data' => 'over yonder',
    'id'   => 3,
  },
);
my $php = serialize(\@rss_feed_results);
```

Comment: sorry for the wrong code. I have corrected it. Actually i am facing issue to unserialize the serialize data done by perl in PHP.

Comment: Just try to unserialize this serialized data "my $php = serialize(\@rss_feed_results);" in php.Here only i m facing issue; to read serialize data in php.

Comment: Your problem is with the serialization in Perl. The data structure you are passing is wrong. Get rid of the `qw`. It's for lists of words, not for hash refs.

Comment: I have already corrected it as mentioned in previous note. Please consider the array is proper but having hash references and serialize it. Then try to unserialize it using php.If you are getting proper data structure then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your RSS feed parser would return a hash, but you use

```
my @rss_feed_result = qw(
   {
      'data'=> 'here',
      'id'=> 1,
   },
);
```

which is the same as

```
my @rss_feed_result = (split ' ', q(
   {
      'data'=> 'here',
      'id'=> 1,
   },
));
```

It would probably work fine if you actually had a reference to a hash.

```
my @rss_feed_result = (
   {
      'data'=> 'here',
      'id'=> 1,
   }
);
```

(Parens optional.)